# Javascript Frames and Framesets

Tags: javascript, html, web

For an assignment, I have to make a web page that switches images in the "RightFrame" by clicking hyperlinks in the "LeftFrame". I'm supposed to use this function:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Assignment</title>
<script>
  function setImage(index)
  {
    if (index == 1)
    {
      RightFrame.document.RightImage.src = "Alumni Hall.jpg";
    }
    if (index == 2)
    {
      RightFrame.document.RightImage.src = "Clock Tower.jpg";
    }
    if (index == 3)
    {
      RightFrame.document.RightImage.src = "Elliot Hall.jpg";
    }
    if (index == 4)
    {
      RightFrame.document.RightImage.src = "Football Field.jpg";
    }
    if (index == 5)
    {
      RightFrame.document.RightImage.src = "North Hall.jpg";
    }
    if (index == 6)
    {
      RightFrame.document.RightImage.src = "South Hall.jpg";
    }
    if (index == 7)
    {
      RightFrame.document.RightImage.src = ="Straughn Hall.jpg";
    }

    return;    
  }    
</script>    
</head>

<frameset cols="20%,*">
  <frame name="LeftFrame" src="left3.html">
  <frame name="RightFrame" src="right1.html">
</frameset>

</html>
```

However, I can't get it to run without cross origin errors. I've been trying everything in my knowledge to get it to work, but I'm still new to this. Help would really be appreciated.

Comment: `frameset`? Are we back in the 90s?

Comment: Yeah, it's an assignment. I asked if I could get it done another way and was told I had to make this work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how they work because those elements are so old :) But I'm sure someone will be able to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution template:

left3.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Assignment</title>

<script>
  function setImage(index)
  {
    parent.frames.RightFrame.window.postMessage(index); 
    return;    
  }    
</script>    
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="setImage(55);">Set Image 55</button>
</body>
</html>
```

right1.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Assignment</title>
<script>
    window.addEventListener("message",function(e)
    {
            alert(e.data);
            setImage(e.data);
    });

  function setImage(index)
  {
    if (index == 55)
    {
      document.getElementById("RightImage").src = "up_arrow.gif";
    }

    return;    
  }    
</script>    
</head>

<body>
   <img src="wt.gif" id="RightImage" >
</body>
</html>
```

1.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Assignment</title>
</head>

<frameset cols="20%,*">
  <frame name="LeftFrame" src="left3.html">
  <frame name="RightFrame" src="right1.html">
</frameset>

</html>
```

Comment: I had to make one small adjustment, but that works great. Thanks so much. I’m so glad I made this post.